# Why is implementation of controlled Hadamard on IBM Q so complex?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, ibm-q-experience, hadamard

With reference to question [how to implement CCH gate](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9421/ways-to-implement-cch-gate) I easily realized that CH gate can be implemented with $\mathrm{Ry}$ gates and $\mathrm{CNOT}$ followingly:

[image: My circuit]

*Note $\theta = \frac{\pi}{4}$ for first $Ry$ gate and $\theta = -\frac{\pi}{4}$ for second one.*

However, when I put $\mathrm{CH}$ gate implemented on IBM Q to circuit, a transpiled circuit has this form:
[image: Transpiled circuit]

So, the first circuit has only two one qubit gates whereas the second one has six such gates. If I understand it correctly, any single qubit gate is on IBM Q eventually replaced by $\mathrm{U3}$ gate with respective parameters.

It seems to me that the second circuit is unnecessary complex.

**Is there any reason why to implement $\mathrm{CH}$ gate in such way or am I missing something?**

Comment: Where are you getting this transpiled circuit from? When I run your initial circuit against the IBMQ simulator, the transpiled circuit contains 2 U3 gates, as expected.

Comment: @met927: Yes, I see the same in this case. But try to put controlled Hadamard (CH gate) instead and run the code. The transpiled code will be as in the second figure.

Comment: I think this is most likely to do with the way the transpilation is being done rather than the way the gate is implemented on the hardware. I imagine in that scenario they are unrolling to a basis that is not the standard `u1`, `u2` and `u3` gates, rather it contains those gates shown. I am not sure why this would be though.

Comment: @met927: And what about IBM Q composer? Try to put CH gate and start e.g. simulation.

Comment: I think this is also to do with how things are transpiled for the simulator, if you execute the circuit on a real device it is transpiled to `u2` gates.

Comment: @met927: I see, just tried also on real quantum processor. Thanks for clues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Summarization based on discussion with user *met927*:

- Transpiled circuit form depends on used backend - it is different for simulator and real quantum processor:

  - On simulator, the $\mathrm{CH}$ gate is transpiled to the circuit shown above
  - On real quantum processor, the gate is implemented with two $\mathrm{U2}$ gates and $\mathrm{CNOT}$ (i.e. like in the first figure in the answer)

**Overall, the $\mathrm{CH}$ gate implementation on IBM Quantum is efficient.**